# Integrating and extending differential forms

Tags: integration, measure-theory, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I am looking for some clarification regarding integrating differential forms. Hopefully this is very basic.

Suppose that I have a compact Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, say $M$, and a subvariety of codimension $k$, say $V$. Let $\alpha$ be a differential $p$-form defined on $M \setminus V$ which (for the sake of argument) admits no continuous extension to the whole of $M$. Suppose further that $\sup_{M \setminus V} |\alpha| \leq C < +\infty$.

If $$\int_{M \setminus V} \alpha \wedge d\beta =0, \quad \forall \beta \in\Omega^{n-p-1}(M),$$ is there a sensible way to make sense of the claim that $$\int_{M} \alpha \wedge d\beta =0, \quad \forall \beta \in \Omega^{n-p-1}(M)?$$

Apologies for how basic this question is but my geometric measure theory is not good! Answers and references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems that your condition implies that $\alpha$ is zero

Comment: You probably want to think to some extent about currents. Is $k\ge 2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I am interested in $k$ at least two but wasn't sure how relevant this would be. As for currents this is what I assumed I would end up being interested in, but it would be nice to understand concretely what is going on before I start worrying about putting the question in higher level frameworks. That being said if you have suggestions about how to proceed in this direction I would still really appreciate it!

Comment: @ArcticChar You are right, the problem I am working on doesn't appear in the above form. I just thought that what I have put above is a very simple way of asking the question, I have edited so that it now means $d \alpha$ is zero if this helps you...